# Programmatically compare IL of two methods

Tags: c#, reflection, intermediate-language

I have a compiled assembly. I want to *programmatically* compare the method implementation of one of the methods in that assembly with something I expect.

Is there a way I can compare their ILs? Even if I can get a byte array representation of any instruction set, I'll be in a good place.

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try using Reflection and compare the IL using byte arrays.

Take a look at this method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbody.getilasbytearray.aspx

Comment: You're the man! That's precisely what I was looking for. And I'd been looking at that method just about an hour ago, and have used it many times earlier. Never thought of it when I needed it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

Using [Mono.Cecil](http://github.com/jbevain/cecil) might be a good place to start. Cecil is a library used to read and modify CLR assemblies, and will do all the file parsing for you as far as grabbing the CIL bytecode.

Another potential library you might be able to use is [Boogie](http://boogie.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 3):

You can dump the assemblies using ildasm and diff the two versions like this:

```
ildasm /ALL /TEXT assembly1.dll > dump1.txt
ildasm /ALL /TEXT assembly2.dll > dump2.txt
fc dump1.txt dump2.txt
```

Comment: That's nice. However, I only need to compare the implementation for a single method in the two assemblies. There may be many differences in the two assemblies.

Answer (score 0):

you can use ildasm.exe from a visual studio command prompt and do something like ildasm.exe dll name

Comment: I meant I need to do it programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ildasm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7dy01k1%28VS.80%29.aspx) or [reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) to extract IL from assembly